# browser window should blink/flash when notifcation in the application

Tags: flash, window, blink

We have a requirment in one of my appilcation that window should blink when application is in minimized state. Could you please suggest ,how to flash or blink the browser window where there is a notification in the application .
Can it be handled in JQuery?

Your help will be appricated. Thanks in advance